# I have an account on Stack Overflow and am registered on Super User, but ask to sign in again

Tags: support

I have an account on Stack Overflow and am registered on Super User (Super User appears on my list of linked accounts). But Super User asks to sign in again when I click on the link from Stack Overflow.

I believe I read a remark about this issue a few weeks ago, but I can't find that post again.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's likely your browser or cookie settings.

Comment: You probably need to enable third-party cookies.

Comment: Maybe related on MSE: [Why do I have to re-log in on all *.SE sites, one after another?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356753/241919)

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes - that was the issue I'd seen. Didn't notice it was already 11 months old. So I'm not alone... but I don't see any definitive answer there? Should I test something?

Comment: Not quite sure what response we can give. Browsers (rightfully so) are encouraging (or forcing) users into cookie policies that don't allow third-party cookies either by default (most) or block them entirely (Safari, as far as I can tell). The different sites have different URL domains (stackoverflow vs superuser vs stackexchange ... etc) so the browsers that prevent third party cookies will not allow you to carry over cookies between the domains. We can't "fix" that... only you can

Comment: Could you list exactly the domains we have to except from the third-party rules to get this working? @AndrewT.'s reference list doesn't seem too sure. In fact, I suspect that from SO's side of things this should be easier to create than from a each single user's side. I.e. compile, for each (major) browser, the steps to follow... It wouldn't be a "fix", but it'd be a big help.

Comment: On the other hand, I'm no expert, but I suspect there must be a way to (securely) hand over authentication between sites without cookies. What's with all these web-services auth protocols? Or at least alleviate the process by, on clicking on the cross-site link, make use land on the login form so the browser can fill it in automatically?

Comment: I have a similar issue with just serverfault.  No issue with superuser, crypto, or unix.